# Multiple checkboxes selected and submit button

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, button, checkbox

I have just finished small project on multiple checkboxes using ajax. The demo can be found here:[demo](http://hibbard.eu/blog/pages/phones_new/) . But now i want to use submit button for filter option. So now after multiple checkboxes are selected and after sumbit button are clicked then only it should change in the phone database. Any help ? Thanks. 
Here is my code:

index.php

```
  <body> 
    <h1>Phones database</h1>

    <table id="phones">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Brand</th>
          <th>Model</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="filter">
      <h2>Filter options</h2>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Samsung" checked>
        <label for="Samsung">Samsung</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="iPhone" checked>
        <label for="iPhone">iPhone</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="HTC" checked>
        <label for="HTC">HTC</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="LG" checked>
        <label for="LG">LG</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Nokia" checked>
        <label for="Nokia">Nokia</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <script>
      function makeTable(data){
        console.log(data);
       var tbl_body = "";
          $.each(data, function() {
            var tbl_row = "";
            $.each(this, function(k , v) {
              tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
            })
            tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
          })

        return tbl_body;
      }

      function getPhoneFilterOptions(){
        var opts = [];
        $checkboxes.each(function(){
          if(this.checked){
            opts.push(this.id);
          }
        });

        return opts;
      }

      function updatePhones(opts){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "submit.php",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {filterOpts: opts},
          success: function(records){
            $('#phones tbody').html(makeTable(records));
          }
        });
      }

      var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
      $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
        var opts = getPhoneFilterOptions();
        updatePhones(opts);
      });

      $checkboxes.trigger("change");
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

submit.php

```
<?php 
require 'Database.php';
#### TEMP SET NAMES FÜR UTF8 ###################################################
include 'Json.php';
  $opts = $_POST['filterOpts'];
  $tmp = array();
  foreach ($opts as $opt) {
        $tmp[] = '"'.$opt.'"';
  }
        $query = 
      'SELECT mobile_phone.id, name, model, price FROM mobile_phone INNER JOIN brand ON brand_id = brand.id WHERE name IN ('.implode(",", $tmp).')';


  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $data   = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
  }

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Do we really need to see all that CSS in this question? Questions should include the least amount of code to illustrate your problem. Therefore please don't just dump your project here and expect answers.

Comment: "So now after multiple checkboxes are selected and after sumbit button are clicked then only it should change in the phone database." What is 'it'? Can you reduce the amount of code and markup here to only what is relevant to your question?

Comment: Hi sorry i have reduce the amount of code.If u check the demo the multiple checkboxes are filtering the phone database. But i want to create button now and after multiple checkbox are selected and button is clicked then only the phone database should get updated.

Answer (score 0):

In your code here.

```
var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
          $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
            var opts = getPhoneFilterOptions();
            updatePhones(opts);
          });
```

remove this line  updatePhones(opts);

Call this function updatePhones(opts) on submit and modify below things in function updatePhones(opts)

Get amount 1 and amount 2 and pass it to submit.php file

Comment: Hi Bharat i have tried to do changes but its not working ..Can you please tell me what t omodify below things in function updatePhones(opts) anmd how to Get amount 1 and amount 2 and pass it to submit.php file ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. did you got the answer or should i try?